# How do I add a button that will transfer to another page in the flutter language?

Tags: flutter

There is a page on which all the current added "cards" of your pets should be displayed (initially, you need to add this "card" by clicking on the "+" button). Clicking on any of these "cards" should switch to the page with this "card" (for example, I can give the contact book in your phone). Each card contains information about the pet (its nickname, gender, age). How do I create something like this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfoPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const InfoPage({super.key});

  @override

  State<InfoPage> createState() => _InfoPageState();

}

class _InfoPageState extends State<InfoPage> {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(

      child: Padding(

        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),

        child: Column(

          children: [

            // heading message

            const Text(

              'Информация о ваших питомцах',

              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),

            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 25),

            // list with the ability to add a pet

            Expanded(

              child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                // add a pet

                

              }),

            ),

          ],

        ),

      ),

    );

  }

}
```

I tried to add a button that will take you to the next page, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: add it after expanded

Comment: good idea is to pass data not the widget on navigation